# In Java Spring, how would I create a URL route that's only visible in development?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

So I'm pretty new to Spring MVC, but I'm wondering if there's a way to setup a route that's visible in a development or test environment but not visible in production?

To differentiate between environments I have a config file (loaded via the "context:property-placeholder" namespace element), and I've setup my controllers similar to what's talked about here - http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Comment: Look into `@Profile`. Create a dev/test controller only in dev/test environments.

Comment: I think the answer is yes, but if you are interested in *how*, you should say how exactly you make the difference between dev and prod environments.

Comment: Right now I differentiate through a variable in a properties file loaded via a "context:property-placeholder" namespace element.

Comment: May be you can have a look at [Interceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your need, but i would prefer usage of profiles to achieve this.

A) By using profile attribute with xml-configuration.

```
<beans profile="myProfileForTest">
  <bean>.... your bean definitions here for this profile
</beans>
<beans profile="myProfileForProd">
  <bean>.... your bean definitions here for this profile
</beans>
```

B) By using @Profile-annotated Spring beans as a type-level annotation for Spring @Component classes (@Repository, @Service, @Controller). Meta-annotations can be useful here.

```
@Profile("myProfileForTest")
public class MySpringBean {
   ....
}
```

Then you can define your active profile by passing in a system parameter:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active="standalone"
```

Or give it to the DispatcherServlet as a init parameter in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
      <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
      <param-value>production</param-value>
  </init-param>
```